# How to override exception message in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I'm having quite a bit of difficulty in getting a custom exception message to return from my Web Api solution.  It's a bit more complicated than that:

[image]

I want to override the read only property of the exception with my own:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public CustomException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

However, I also have a global exception handler:

```
public class GlobalExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception.Message == "Password has already been used in the past...1")
        {
            throw new CustomException("some msg", context.Exception);
        }

        NLogger.LogError("Global Error Handler", context.Exception);
    }
}
```

When I throw the error I do so like:

```
if (some condition)) throw new CustomException("some msg");
```

And then I catch it in the method like:

```
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    NLogger.LogError(ex);
    throw;
}
```

How can I set the message to be "some msg"? What I'm trying to do is have the api return 1-2 use case related error messages with customErrors mode set to on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
    new HttpResponseMessage
    {
         StatusCode = code,
         ReasonPhrase = phrase,
         Content = new StringContent(body)
    });
```